# Set Database Options in an Entity Framework Code First Database

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

My DB keeps getting detached with a 9001 "Log for database not available" error. This seems to be due to the fact that Auto Close is set to True on the DB.

How can I change this value from within .NET so I don't have to keep firing up SQL Management Studio to change it manually every time the DB is recreated?

Answer (score 0):

In Powershell

```
import-module "sqlps" -DisableNameChecking
$servername = "my_server_instance"
$sql="ALTER DATABASE <DATABASE_NAME> set auto_close off"
invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance $servername -Query $sql
```